# Can table columns be used to compare with results from aggregate functions using HAVING Clause?

Tags: mysql, sql

While I know I can clearly use a nested SQL query to fetch number of employees whose salary is greater than the average employee salary, the query with **HAVING** clause does not. Anything specific that I am missing?

```
mysql> select count(*) from employee 
       where salary > (select avg(salary) from employee) ;

+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|        4 |
+----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

`

This does not work.

```
    mysql> select count(*) from employee group by salary having salary > avg(salary);
```

> Empty set (0.00 sec)

Comment: Group By missing. You should use Group By when using Having.

Comment: It is still fetching 0 records.

Comment: What are you trying to do?  The first query makes sense.  The second doesn't do anything particularly useful.

Comment: Then you should not use having there. the first query is fine.

Comment: The question was can we use aggregate function results to compare against column values using Having

Comment: once you aggregate with `GROUP BY`, you don't have specific individual rows in the result set. `HAVING` can only restrict results further based on the aggregated results without an individual row for comparison.

Comment: Thanks @danblack. This possibly explains why it won't allow me to use columns for comparing with average salary using HAVING clause. I am assuming there is no way in which such a functionality be achieved using Having clause.

Comment: You might want to read up on mysql order of operations for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52354180/how-can-table-columns-be-compared-with-aggregate-function-using-having-clause#52354180

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the correct answer to this which I was looking for is:

```
SELECT fname , salary
FROM employee
GROUP BY salary
HAVING salary > (SELECT avg(salary) FROM employee);
```

Answer (score 0):

**if your intention is to use aggregated function then you can try this. otherwise, the first query is fine.**

```
SELECT count(*) Count
FROM (
  SELECT
    salary,
    AVG(salary) OVER () AS AvgSalary
  FROM employee 
) s
WHERE salary> AvgSalary
```

Comment: I am aware of this. My question is specific to HAVING clause.